# If statement Object boolean not working

Tags: java, oop, object, boolean

I'm trying to check for a persons age using another object in another class, for some reason the **areThey** boolean returns false no matter what. The following code that I implemented is_

```
  public class main {    
    public static void main(String[] args){    
      Obj object = new Obj();    
      object.areTheyOldEnough();

      if(object.areTheyOldEnough() == true){
          System.out.println("They are old enough!");
      }else{
          System.out.println("They are not old enough!");
      }
    }
}

public class Obj {
    private int age = 15;
    private boolean areThey;

    public boolean areTheyOldEnough() {
        if (age > 12) {
            boolean areThey = true;
        }
        return areThey;    
    } 
}
```

Comment: Calling an instance of a class `Object` is not a very good idea. You should read up on naming conventions.

Comment: Independently your question you should know that: Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each internal word capitalized. (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html ) . I mean that you should define your class: public class Obj

Comment: Beyond that `if (booleanMethod() == true)` is also bad practice. You see,  `if (areTheyOldEnough())` is even easier to read!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is called **shadowing**; here:

That **most inner** declaration of :

```
if (age > 12) {
  boolean areThey = true;
```

Is simply wrong, that should read:

```
areThey = true;
```

instead. The point is: you are declaring a **new** variable of that name, and give that the value `true`. But that variable vanishes in thin air when that if-block is "left" ... and what is returned is the value of the **field** `areThey` within your `obj` class. And that one **still** has its initial default value of `false`.

And beyond that: **naming** is a real problem in your code. Use names that A) comply to java coding standards; so class names start UpperCase for example; B) **mean** something.

In other words: the name **Object** doesn't mean anything (besides creating yet another name clash with the java.lang.Object class name). Better call it "testInstance" or something like that - as said: use names that **mean** something.

Answer (score 0):

You have two boolean variables of the same name - one is a local variable, which you are setting in your method (inside the if block), and the other is a an instance variable which you are returning.

You don't need any boolean variable, just write :

```
public boolean areTheyOldEnough() {
    return age > 12;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you mixed visibilities of field and local variable

```
public class obj {

public int age = 15;
public boolean areThey; //initialized to false as default value for boolean

public boolean areTheyOldEnough() {
   if (age > 12) {
       boolean areThey = true; //create new local variable with the same name as field, 
                               // but visible just in scope of if-block
    }
    return areThey; // return value from field
}
```

Answer (score 0):

correct your code as follow :

```
public class main {

public static void main(String[] args){

  obj Object = new obj();

  if(obj.areTheyOldEnough()){
      System.out.println("They are old enough!");
  } else{
      System.out.println("They are not old enough!");
  }
}
```

and your obj class will be :

```
public class obj {
public int age = 15;
// it is not required, but if you need for other methods,
// you can define it
public boolean areThey;

public boolean areTheyOldEnough() {
    return age > 12;
    // or if you need set variable areThey, so use following codes
   /*
      areThey = age > 12;
      return areThey;
   */
}
```